# SharePoint List Validation

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-online

I am struggling to have the following validation working in SharePoint:

```
      Column                   |    Column
      Overall Status           |    Comments / Delay Explanations 
      "On Track" or "Delayed"
```

Based on the **Overall Status** if the result is "Delayed", the users should enter a minimum of (8) characters notes in the **Comments / Delay Explanations** column.

I have entered the characters validation in the **Comments / Delay Explanations** column, but I can't get the List Validation formula I wrote to work... Could someone please help me?  Thanks!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8Qpg.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2xRP.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, hope this will help someone else :)

Althought I couldn't get the 8 characters to work at the same time :(

=IF([Overall Status]="Delayed",AND([Comments / Delay Explanations]<>""),TRUE)